# What is the maximum number of classes can have in my program?

Tags: java, blackberry, java-me

Because when i compile i get error:

> I/O Error: Cannot run program "jar": CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified

but when i delete one class program compiles without problems.

So how many classes maximum i can put in my program?

Or is the problem somewhere else?

Comment: I read somewhere that there's a limit on the number of classes in a single package. Try refactoring your package to see if that helps. (This may have been for old versions of the tools, so if there was indeed a problem, it might not be an issue for you.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [this post in the BB forums](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/Number-of-classes-per-project-limitation-exceeding-which-causes/td-p/615467), the problem usually goes away if you add the `bin` folder for your JDK to the system PATH. (On Windows, this is Control Panel -> System -> Advanced system settings.)